# Dividers disappear in PullToRefreshListView

Tags: java, android

I want to use Pull-To-Refresh Library in my App that is already developed and the source is [here](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh).

I am running the launcher sample on Android 2.3.5.

The problem is when we add the `PullToRefreshListView` to our List with black background, the white separators between the items (dividers) disappear.

It is the same for me in my own app and in the sample of the link. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should modify the activity_ptr_list.xml file. I forgot to fix the `android:divider`:

```
<com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
        android:id="@+id/pull_refresh_list"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="#FFFFFF"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to apply below code 
its is working programatically.
listview.getRefreshableView().setDividerHeight(0);

Answer (score 0):

try to apply next style to your ListView:

`<item name="android:cacheColorHint">@android:color/transparent</item>`